# Adding custom template to mail_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mail-form

I'm attempting to follow the documentation for the [Mail_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form)  gem to add a custom email template. The documentation states:

To customize the e-mail template that is used create a file called `contact.erb` in `app/views/mail_form`. Take a look at lib/mail_form/views/mail_form/contact.erb in this repo to see how the default template works.

Also, I found this [issue in the repo](http://www.github.com/plataformatec/mail_form/issues/1) and did the same:

I created a mail_for.rb file in initializers and added `MailForm::Notifier.template_root = File.join(Rails.root, "app", "views")`, to the file.

I created a mail_form directory in views and added a `contact.erb` file and copied the default template to it.

However, when I restart the server I get the following error:

> Booting WEBrick
>   => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
>   => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
>   => Ctrl-C to shutdown server Exiting /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionmailer-4.2.5/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:569:in
>   `method_missing': undefined method`template_root=' for
>   MailForm::Notifier:Class (NoMethodError)  from
>   /Users/Tony/Desktop/Corner_Stone/vagrant/src/cornerstone/config/initializers/mail_form.rb:1:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`load'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'   from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`load_dependency'     from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in`
>   block in load_config_initializer'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in
>   `instrument'  from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in`
>   load_config_initializer'     from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'  from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in`
>   each'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in
>   `block in <class:Engine>'     from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
>   instance_exec'   from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
>   `run'     from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`
>   block in run_initializers'   from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in
>   `block in tsort_each'     from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in`
>   block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'   from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in
>   `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'  from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in`
>   each_strongly_connected_component_from'  from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in
>   `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'     from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in`
>   each'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in
>   `tsort_each_child'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in`
>   call'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in
>   `each_strongly_connected_component_from'  from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in`
>   block in each_strongly_connected_component'  from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in
>   `each'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in`
>   call'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in
>   `each_strongly_connected_component'   from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in`
>   tsort_each'  from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in
>   `tsort_each'  from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`
>   run_initializers'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in
>   `initialize!'     from
>   /Users/Tony/Desktop/Corner_Stone/vagrant/src/cornerstone/config/environment.rb:5:in`
>   '    from
>   /Users/Tony/Desktop/Corner_Stone/vagrant/src/cornerstone/config.ru:3:in
>   `require'     from
>   /Users/Tony/Desktop/Corner_Stone/vagrant/src/cornerstone/config.ru:3:in`
>   block in '     from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in
>   `instance_eval'   from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`
>   initialize'  from
>   /Users/Tony/Desktop/Corner_Stone/vagrant/src/cornerstone/config.ru:in
>   `new'     from
>   /Users/Tony/Desktop/Corner_Stone/vagrant/src/cornerstone/config.ru:in`
>   '  from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in
>   `eval'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in`
>   new_from_string'     from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in
>   `parse_file'  from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in`
>   build_app_and_options_from_config'   from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in
>   `app'     from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in`
>   app'     from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in
>   `wrapped_app'     from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in`
>   log_to_stdout'   from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in
>   `start'   from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in`
>   block in server'     from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in
>   `tap'     from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`
>   server'  from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in
>   `run_command!'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`
>   '    from
>   /Users/Tony/Desktop/Corner_Stone/vagrant/src/cornerstone/bin/rails:9:in
>   `require'     from
>   /Users/Tony/Desktop/Corner_Stone/vagrant/src/cornerstone/bin/rails:9:in`
>   '    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in
>   `load'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`
>   call'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in
>   `call'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in`
>   run'     from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.4/bin/spring:49:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in`
>   load'    from
>   /Users/Tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /Users/Tony/Desktop/Corner_Stone/vagrant/src/cornerstone/bin/spring:13:in`
>   require'     from
>   /Users/Tony/Desktop/Corner_Stone/vagrant/src/cornerstone/bin/spring:13:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from bin/rails:3:in`load'  from bin/rails:3:in
>   `'

Everything works when I remove the code in the `mail_form.rb` file, but I want to customize the mail notification to my liking. The error says undefined method `template_root=' for MailForm::Notifier:Class`, but I don't know what it means. I'm still learning so this error is a little over my head, Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with the same problem. It was quite frustrating that their documentation is lacking information about custom template. It's so nebulous. I need to give credit to a colleague of mine for finding a quick solution. He is way more skilled than me in Ruby.

Here's what he did:

1. Remove/delete the `mail_form.rb` file in initializers. My colleague thinks the gem already does this by default, and after testing this theory I guess he was right. So you don't need the file.
2. Expend your `External Libraries` folder in your project tree and find the `mail_form` folder. I'm using RubyMine so I don't know if your software will show this. tell me if if it doesn't and I will update my answer and paste the initial template code.
3. Inside the `mail_form` folder, expand and access the following file `lib>mail_form>views>mail_form>contact.erb`. This `.erb` file is the initial template used by the gem.
4. Copy/paste the content of the file accessed above into the `contact.erb` file that you previously created inside your mail_form directory in your `views` directory. This will become your custom template.
5. Once this is done, you now have full control over the email template, so modify the code to your liking.